# Getting a Method Signature from a Native method, from Java

Tags: java, dll, methods, java-native-interface, method-signature

I am working to call native methods via Java/JNI, in Windows.  The basics are fine.  My problem is that I do not know the exact method signature of one of the methods.  I have its name.

Does anyone know of a way to get the exported methods and signatures from a loaded DLL from the Java side?

Comment: Do you not know which method you are going to call until runtime?  I imagine that's something you'd want to do within the native .dll

Comment: And what would you do if you knew at runtime the correct signature of the method? Pretty hard to call a function that way (except if you want to create all possible permutations of possible parameters.. no great concept). I don't understand why you can't just look up the sig from the export table and use that?

Comment: Do you want to create the native method on Java side or do you already have access to the native interface on Java-side? If you do you can query all java overload method throughout reflection.

Comment: This is not a runtime issue, it's an attempt to learn about the methods available from a DLL without proper documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - NDK Shared libraries extracting relevant JNI hooks with nm / objdump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128810/android-ndk-shared-libraries-extracting-relevant-jni-hooks-with-nm-objdump)

Answer (score 0):

No, all you get from JNI naming convention is the name of exported function - and even this on condition that the library is not using RegisterNatives(). You also know that the first two parameters are pointers. From here, you can try to disassemble the function as you would for any other undocumented exported function.