# Viewing JNI Function Signature from .so File

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Given a shared object file with a compiled JNI interface, is there a way to view the actual function signature in the .so file?

```
readelf -a <library>.so | grep "<function name>"
```

shows that the function exists, but does not provide any further information other than:

```
39: 000ea0f5 1548 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 8 _Z12<functionname>CppRN2cv3Mat
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "NO".

Sometimes, you can find some hint that could help, see e.g. *[Android - NDK Shared libraries extracting relevant JNI hooks with nm / objdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128810/android-ndk-shared-libraries-extracting-relevant-jni-hooks-with-nm-objdump)*. But if the JNI library uses **RegisterNatives()**, you will not even see the JNI functions in the exported list.